# how to keep the recently view files on tab

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

how to keep the recently viewed/edited files on tab? For previous version, most recently viewed/edited files are always on tab, very convenient. But for this version, it is not the case. Have to find/open recent files again and again. Any one know if there is a way to keep the most recently opened files on tab? Thanks a lot.